# Current Main Areas of Research in Model Theory

Tags: big-list, model-theory

Could someone gives a general picture of the *present* state of Model Theory as a field? What are the current main areas and directions of research? What are some examples of the current experts and the most influential work in those areas?

Comment: I'm not expert in logics but probably Hrushovski's work about approximate subgroup is one of the most exciting applications of model theory in recent years. Actually, on a second thought, probably everything written by Hrushovski (say Mordell-Lang) should be considered as influential work.

Comment: I cast the final vote to close. I am very far from being an expert in model theory, but this question just seems way too broad to me (like it would be for any field of mathematics).